# The span of three nonzero vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ is a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$. Proving this wrong

Tags: linear-algebra

Could I prove the statement in the title with a set of three co planar vectors? As there subspace would be 2 dimensional.

Comment: those three must be linearly independent, if they aren't then could be even 1-dimensional

Comment: If $v\neq 0$, what's the span of $\{v,2v,3v\}$?

Comment: As @janmarqz says, the vectors need to be linearly independent. If you took the span of three linearly dependent vectors they would only span a line - an 1-dimensional subspace of $ \mathbb{R} $

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly the correct idea - three vectors which lie in a plane would disprove the statement. [You can use the scalar triple product to show that they are coplanar.] This is because the statement does not have the words 'linearly independent' vectors. You can take this to the extreme using the suggestion in the comments as well: if $v \neq 0$, then $\{v,2v,3v\}$ is a 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ instead of a 2-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Your counterexample will work.  The key thing to note is that, unless the three nonzero vectors are linearly independent, they will not span a three dimensional space:  it will be either two or one dimensional.